# Python variable descriptors for use with radish framework

Tags: python

I'm currently using the radish bdd framework to do some testing on a Phonebook class. I've written a step as such:

```
@given("I have the number {number1:g} and the name {name1:w}")
def have_record(step, number1, name1):
    step.context.number1 = number1
    step.context.name1 = name1
```

I was having an issue with the step not being recognised and figured out that the `{name1:w}` was wrong, as it was originally `{name1:g}`. The feature passes in a name, which is a string and as such using `{name1:g}` does not work, as I understand this declares the variable as a floating point.

I've tried to find what types I can declare these variables as in python and how I can do such, however can't seem to find anything. My current understanding is that using `:g` will declare as floating point and `:w` will declare as string, yet I don't know what other types I can declare and how to declare them.

Does anyone know what this is called and how I can use this?

Answer (score 0):

The variable descriptors can be found in the [*Radish-bdd Documentation*](https://radish.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#step-pattern) under the *Step Pattern* section.

`:g` type is a general number format

`:w` type is letters and underscore format

All types can be found in the documentation including others such as `MathExpression` and `DateTime`

Reminder to self to read the documentation properly...